# Open file/folder with (Shortcut / Quick Action) for VS Code, Git Kraken

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, shortcuts

I was wondering if there is a way to have a shortcut similar to the Windows context menu for Git Kraken and Visual Studio Code, but on Mac OS (as a quick action) to easily open files or folders (depending on what is needed).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did resarch, a lot.
I found a way using [**Automator**](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac)

[image: example-quick-action]

**Download** at this repo: https://github.com/rbatty19/mac-os-automators/

[image: github-ss-installers]

Also, If you can do it by yourself, check this readme file how the were built: https://github.com/rbatty19/mac-os-automators/blob/main/factory.md

[image: github-factory-ss]